# Is chicken Slaughtered by only one man halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food, dhabihah

Recently I had to buy chickens which were slaughtered by one man due to lack of man-power. The slaughterer had to apply body weight on the chicken to hold it steady. Other than this, everything looked normal to me. But later I found out there's a probability of these chickens being haram because of the way those were slaughtered. If I would have known this fact, I would have helped the slaughterer in the slaughtering.

My question is, will the slaughter be accepted in a halal way?

Comment: Did the chicken unnecessary suffer in the process?

Comment: You should have Googled the conditions and methods of Halal slaughter!

Comment: @Aboudi nothing more than the usual; and not unnecessarily for sure. And as it happened so fast, I didn't have a chance for googling.

Comment: Only this reason that the chicken is slaughtered by a single person is not necessary to tell that it is haram, it depends upon the procedure of slaughtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The slaughterer had to apply body weight on the chicken to hold it steady

If he pulled back the wings and put pressure on them to hold it down (as is customarily done) then there is no issue (the chicken won't have felt it either). If he exerted pressure on the torso and the chicken was suffocated or crushed and that caused its death then its counted as ميتة (carrion) and not halal <sup>[5:3](https://quran.com/5/3)</sup>

There is no condition on the number of people involved in a slaughter. Chickens are usually slaughtered by a single person as can be goats, cows and camels (though ropes are used here).

### Conclusion

Yes generally it would be considered halal.